# Need form to present field errors prior to submit

Tags: php, forms, tooltip, form-submit

I have a form on my site for visitors to submit data and upload an image file.

Currently... if a visitor makes errors on the form, the errors are presented to them upon 'submit'.

I would like to set the form up so that any errors they may make in filling out the form, such as; wrong image type, incomplete (required fields), etc. are presented to the user for them to correct before they can submit the form.

I've seen various examples of forms that do this.

Some of them present 'tooltip' style error notifications (which I am font of), and some present the errors in other ways.

I have researched how to do this, and I keep running into walls.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some technical details how you want to validate the form: at  the client (and with an ajax callback if required) or on the server. If you want to use tooltips, you probably want to validate your form in the client. So you need probably some kind of  `javascript` to validate your input and a library to display tooltips. There are plenty of both around, so you'll have to choose.

Comment: You're describing "client side validation". It is usually done using JavaScript. There are lots of ways to do it. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow doesn't really support questions about where to start. Search Stack Overflow for one of the "walls" you've run into and you may find someone has already asked about it. Welcome, and don't get discouraged if this question is closed. It doesn't mean we don't like you. Just ask a new question kind of like "I've decide to do X using Y but I'm running into error Z. Here's my code. What am I missing?"

Comment: Thanks guys. Appreciated. I will dig around for more info on "client side validation". If I run into a snag, I may revisit with a specific X,Y to Z question.

Comment: Here's what I found so far... It's a start. 

[link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp)